# How do I iterate through nested dictionaries in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

Still new to Python and need a little help here. I've found some answers for iterating through a list of dictionaries but not for nested dictionaries in a list of dictionaries.

Here is the a rough structure of a single dictionary within the dictionary list

```
[{ 'a':'1',
'b':'2',
'c':'3',
'd':{ 'ab':'12',
      'cd':'34',
      'ef':'56'},
'e':'4',
'f':'etc...'
}]



dict_list = [{ 'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':{ 'ab':'12','cd':'34', 'ef':'56'}, 'e':'4', 'f':'etc...'}, { 'a':'2', 'b':'3', 'c':'4', 'd':{ 'ab':'23','cd':'45', 'ef':'67'}, 'e':'5', 'f':'etcx2...'},{},........,{}]
```

That's more or less what I am looking at although there are some keys with lists as values instead of a dictionary but I don't think I need to worry about them right now although code that would catch those would be great.

Here is what I have so far which does a great job of iterating through the json and returning all the values for each 'high level' key.

```
import ujson as json

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    json_text = f.read()

dict_list = json.loads(json_text)

for dic in dict_list:
    for val in dic.values():
        print(val)
```

Here is the first set of values that are returned when that loop runs

```
1
2
3
{'ab':'12','cd':'34','ef':'56'}
4
etc...
```

What I need to be able to do pick specific values from the top level and go one level deeper and grab specific values in that nested dictionary and append them to a list(s). I'm sure I am missing a simple solution. Maybe I'm looking at multiple loops?

Comment: You can use a recursive function for that, the base condition will be that a value is primitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about checking for the instance type using `isinstance` (of course only works for one level deeper). Might not be the best way though

```
for dic in dict_list:
    for val in dic.values():
        if not isinstance(val, dict):
            print(val)
        else:    
            for val2 in val.values():
                print (val2)

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 12
# 34
# 56
# 4
# etc...
# 2
# 3
```

Comment: This is the faster solution if inner dictionaries are expected to be rare (compared to duck typing).

Comment: @kabanus: Here based on the data list in the question, I assumed that there is only one level of nested dictionaries. For multiple nested depths, your recursion is the way to go. +1 on your solution

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes. Only one level deep. At least as far as I can tell. There is 40K plus dictionaries in this dataset.

Comment: @MixedBeans: For just one level deep, my answer should work fine

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks. I added a little more detail to what output I was looking for  right after I posted. I didn't expect such fast responses. I only had the print statement to see what was being returned.

Comment: @Bazingaa  Does it make more sense to define a function(s) so I have some flexibility with what I chose from both the high level and second level dictionaries?

Comment: @MixedBeans: It is possible but it is in itself a non-trivial question on its own. I would suggest to not constantly modify your existing question for new answers but post a new question.

Comment: Got it! I'll edit this question back to the original and ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Following the ducktype style encouraged with Python, just guess everything has a `.values` member, and catch it if they do not:

```
import ujson as json

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    json_text = f.read()

dict_list = json.loads(json_text)

for dic in dict_list:
    for val in dic.values():
        try:
            for l2_val in val.values():
                print(l2_val)
        except AttributeError:
            print(val)
```

[Bazingaa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55186045/6881240) solution would be faster if inner dictionaries are expected to be rare.

Of course, any more "deep" and you would need some recursion probably:

```
def print_dict(d):
    for val in d.values():
       try:
           print_dict(val)
        except AttributeError:
           print(val)
```

Comment: It should be `l2_val` instead of `l2-val`

Comment: @Bazingaa I should have just compiled it through you :) thanks!